# Add schema from DB to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database which was created by my CMS installation named `BlogDB` and another database (named `dbemp`)  which I am currently using for my website. My host allows me to use only one database. So, I wanted to create the schema from BlogDB to dbemp. Can this be done?

Also, I do not want to delete the schema from my original DB, neither overwrite it and it must continue working as it is. Just the new new tables etc. have to be added.

Comment: Does your host allow you to generate SQL scripts from the database? You could generate the create script and then run it against the other database. Since you are using SQL Server (although you don't say which version) you could place all the new entities within a schema in your `dbemp` database. That way there wouldn't be any name clashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automagically create tables with a similar structure by using

CREATE TABLE db2.DESTINATION SELECT * FROM db1.SOURCE;

This creates the same structure, but with certain problems. It will not take over indexes, so you need to recreate all constraints in the destination tables again.